# Reinterpret terminal output

Tags: text-processing, terminal, escape-characters

I have a program that executes some commands in a terminal (for example `apt-get update`) and stores the output.

How can I reinterpret the output, so I can remove all information that is not needed ?

For example, the raw output is (this is just a fraction of the output):

```
Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 1%

Reading package lists... 6%

Reading package lists... 6%

Reading package lists... 26%

Reading package lists... 32%

Reading package lists... 32%

Reading package lists... 39%

Reading package lists... 39%

Reading package lists... 53%

Reading package lists... 65%

Reading package lists... 65%

Reading package lists... 68%

Reading package lists... 68%

Reading package lists... 83%

Reading package lists... 84%

Reading package lists... 84%

Reading package lists... 86%

Reading package lists... 86%

Reading package lists... 88%

Reading package lists... 88%

Reading package lists... 90%

Reading package lists... 90%

Reading package lists... 92%

Reading package lists... 92%

Reading package lists... 93%

Reading package lists... 93%

Reading package lists... 94%

Reading package lists... 94%

Reading package lists... 95%

Reading package lists... 95%

Reading package lists... 96%

Reading package lists... 96%

Reading package lists... 97%

Reading package lists... 97%

Reading package lists... 98%

Reading package lists... 98%

Reading package lists... 99%

Reading package lists... 99%

Reading package lists... 99%

Reading package lists... 99%

Reading package lists... Done
```

and it should be interpreted like when you execute the normal command in bash, being the final output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: looks like you want `apt-get -q`

Comment: @glennjackman please note that apt-get is an example, i am looking for a generic solution for any script or command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col -b` (on Linux it's part of the util-linux package; in base system elsewhere).

> col filters out reverse (and half-reverse) line feeds so the output
>          is in the correct order, with only forward and half-forward line
>          feeds.

Answer (score 1):

You recorded the output of the command to a terminal, so it decided to use terminal features. Specifically, `apt-get` uses carriage return characters to move the cursor back to the beginning of the current line and overwrite the text that was on the line.

To emulate the effect of carriage returns, remove all text before one:

```
<transcript sed 's/.*\r//'
```

If you only want to record the output and not display it to a user, use redirection instead of `script` or the like. Then `apt-get` will display plain text.

Comment: You inspired me to find a easier solution using redirection. If you run from the application `whatever-command | tee /dev/null` will give you the output formatted like in the terminal.

Comment: @Tk421 or just `whatever-command | cat`